# Swap leaf label of Tree in NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, tree, nltk

I have parse this tagged sentence using NLTK's `RegexpParser` : *the dog chased the black cat* and I used the following `grammar`:

`tagged_ = [('the', 'DT'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('chased', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('black', 'JJ'), ('cat', 'NN')]`

`grammar = """NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
             VP: {<MD>?<VBD>}"""
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(tagged_)
print(result)
result.draw()`

this is the output of the `print(result)` and `result.draw()`:

`(S (NP the/DT dog/NN) (VP chased/VBD) (NP the/DT black/JJ cat/NN))`
[image: Tree]

Now I want to reorder the leaves wherein the `(VP chased/VBD)` and `(NP the/DT dog/NN)` exchanged to be like this:

`S (VP chased/VBD) (NP the/DT dog/NN) (NP the/DT black/JJ cat/NN))` then display the `['chased','the','dog','the','black','cat']`. Is there any way?

Comment: What should be the idea of the algorithm? Simply shift the verb phrase of a given sentence in the first position?

Comment: Its like *Rule-based reordering*, I can't find any codes that parse the **SUBJECT-OBJECT-VERB** of a sentence using NLTK. So what I just did is to parse the Noun Phrase and verb Phrase. My idea in reordering the English sentence rule (SVO) to **VERB-SUBJECT-OBJECT** is to give the meaning of the input sentence into other language who does not follow the SVO rule but follow VSO rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a nltk.Tree object as a tuple of two values. The first value is the name of the root node and the second value is a list that contains child trees or leaves. You can build a complex tree by append child trees in the list of the root:

```py
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> tree = Tree('S', [])
>>> np = Tree('NP', ['The', 'dog'])
>>> tree.append(np)
>>> vp = Tree('VP', ['barks'])
>>> tree.append(vp)
>>> print tree
(S (NP the dog) (VP barks))
```

You can iterate over all sub trees by `tree.subtrees()`:

```py
>>> for sub in tree.subtrees():
...     print sub
(S (NP the dog) (VP barks) 
(NP the dog)
(VP barks)
```

How you can see the method outputs all sub trees, i.e. in a complex tree you get sub trees, sub sub trees, sub sub sub trees... So in your case you should better gain access by slices of the first tree level:

```py
>>> new = Tree('S', [])
>>> for i in xrange(len(tree)):
...     if tree[i].label() == 'VP':
...         new.insert(0, tree[i])
...     else:
...         new.append(tree[i])

>>> print new
(S (VP barks) (NP the dog))
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but what if input sentence is unknown? My only problem is, from the tags of each tokens, write a grammar to identify the **SUBJECT, VERB OBJECT** in the sentence  using the `nltk.RegexpParser` and `parse`  which return `Tree` then reorder it to **VERB-SUBJECT-OBJECT** .

Comment: There is no parser in the standard environment of nltk that can determine grammatical relations (subject, object etc.). An I suppose there is also no simple strategy to dedect grammatical relations out of phrases, except for simple sentences. The Standford Dependency Parser, that can be used together with nltk, is able to parse subject, object and so on. See here for web demo: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/

Comment: Then thank you again sir. I think I should use corpus-based. What my program does is a knowledge-based approach translation Sir but the limitations is for a simple sentences only. Is there a way like you said: " _An I suppose there is also no simple strategy to detect grammatical relations out of phrases, except for **simple sentences**_ ", and please check my algorithm and codes here. https://github.com/tomcrack/EYT

Comment: Thank you, now i get it. But sorry, i don't be familiar with machine tranlation.

Comment: OK I inderstand sir. But can you recommend me an easy tool for creating GUI for python. The one that easy to understand. Actually, Im just new to python programming.